# Running application using cmd.exe while inside the console in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, console

I have an `.exe` application. When I run it from the console in Windows 8.1 by executing a command

```
C:/Path/To/My/App/MyApp.exe
```

it starts and works just fine.

But I need to run it through the `cmd.exe` from the console by running the command

```
cmd.exe /C "C:/Path/To/My/App/MyApp.exe"
```

When I do this, the app starts but after a couple of seconds it gives me this error message:
[image: error message]

How can I fix this? What can be the reason for such behavior?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why do need to run it that way? Since we have no idea what your application does, it seems an odd thing to do. The difference in this way of running is that the application's parent has terminated, though there is no way of knowing if this is relevant. There may be entries in the event log or the application's own log that will give a clue.

Comment: Some record in the Application log? take a look in [Event Viewer](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-event-viewer.htm). What about `cmd.exe /C start "" "C:/Path/To/My/App/MyApp.exe"`?

Comment: Slashes are not usual for Windows paths. Try backslashes instead.

Comment: Why call from cmd.exe?  Why not provide with `start`  or  `Call myamy app.exe ` ?